# I'm done button not enabled when I'm done

Tags: bug, review-queues, suggested-edits

In the first post review queue, I thought that editing was needed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13732220). There was already an edit pending (`edit (1)`), so I clicked on that one and voted to approve it. It's unclear to me if the required number of approve votes was reached.

Going back to the review, the "I'm done" button is still not enabled. I don't want to upvote or downvote, because I can't judge on the amount of research done for this question.

Of course I could still skip, but then it remains in the queue and other people have the same issue, too.

[image: I'm done]

Comment: I believe the correct action here, if the edit fixed all of the issues, is to press "No Action Needed", since you haven't changed anything, the button won't ungrey itself. For it to ungrey, you would need to approve and edit, vote, comment, flag, or close the question.

Comment: Or, you know, skip.